How to manage multiple instances of the same subservice type with unique separators in a dynamic JavaScript table?
I am working on a web application where users can add multiple instances of the same subservice type to a table. Each instance should create a new separator with the subservice name in the table. The problem arises when I add the same subservice type multiple times with different names. Only the last name is displayed in the separator, and the previous instance's line items are not shown.
I tried to generate unique IDs for each subservice instance and ensure that each separator is associated with the correct instance. I expected that each subservice instance would have its own separator and display all related line items. However, the separator only displays the last added instance's name, and only its line items are shown in the table.
Current Code:
Here is my code for adding a new subservice and updating the separator name in the LV.
function addNewSubService(service) {
        const subserviceContainer = document.getElementById(`${service}-subservices`);
        if (!subserviceContainer) {
            console.error(`Container für ${service} nicht gefunden`);
            return;
        }

        const index = subserviceContainer.children.length;
        const subserviceInstanceId = generateSubserviceInstanceId(service, index);  // Eindeutige ID generieren
        addSubService(service, index, subserviceInstanceId);

        const nameElement = document.getElementById(`${service}-name-${index}`);
        if (nameElement) {
            nameElement.addEventListener('input', () => updateLvSeparator(service, nameElement.value));
        }

        // Füge die neue Teilleistung dem Leistungsverzeichnis hinzu
        const teilleistungId = getTeilleistungenFromOffer({ subservices: [{ type: service.replace('-', '_'), instance_id: subserviceInstanceId }] });
        loadLeistungsverzeichnis(teilleistungId, true);  // Wichtig: append = true, damit bestehende Teilleistungen nicht überschrieben werden
    }

function updateTeilleistungName(service, index, uniqueId) {
        const serviceName = document.getElementById(`${service}-name-${index}-${uniqueId}`).value;
        console.log(`Updating teilleistung name: ${serviceName} for service: ${service}, index: ${index}, uniqueId: ${uniqueId}`);

        // Finde den richtigen Separator mit der passenden uniqueId
        const separatorRow = document.querySelector(`tr.table-secondary[data-subservice-id="${uniqueId}"]`);
        if (separatorRow) {
            separatorRow.innerHTML = `<td colspan="7">Teilleistung ${serviceName}</td>`;
        }
    }

function addLvEntry(serviceType, serviceName) {
        console.log(`Adding LV entry: ${serviceType}, serviceName: ${serviceName}`);

        const lvBody = document.getElementById('lv-body');
        const tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.classList.add('teilleistung-entry');
        tr.dataset.serviceType = serviceType;

        tr.innerHTML = `
        <td colspan="7" class="teilleistung-header">Teilleistung ${serviceName}</td>
    `;

        lvBody.appendChild(tr);
    }

function generateSubserviceInstanceId(service, index) {
        return `${service}-${index}-${Date.now()}`;
    }

function loadLeistungsverzeichnis(teilleistungen, append = false) {
        fetch(`/api/leistungsverzeichnis?teilleistungen=${teilleistungen}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                const lvBody = document.getElementById('lv-body');

                // Wenn nicht angehängt wird, clear das LV-Body
                if (!append) {
                    lvBody.innerHTML = '';
                }

                const existingLvIds = new Set();
                lvBody.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(row => {
                    existingLvIds.add(row.dataset.lvId);
                });

                let currentTeilleistung = '';
                let currentTeilleistungName = '';  // To store the name of the current subservice

                data.forEach(lv => {
                    if (!existingLvIds.has(lv.id.toString())) {
                        // Add separator if the teilleistung has changed
                        if (lv.teilleistung !== currentTeilleistung || lv.teilleistung_name !== currentTeilleistungName) {
                            currentTeilleistung = lv.teilleistung;
                            currentTeilleistungName = lv.teilleistung_name;

                            const separatorRow = document.createElement('tr');
                            separatorRow.classList.add('table-secondary');
                            separatorRow.innerHTML = `<td colspan="7">Teilleistung ${currentTeilleistung} - ${currentTeilleistungName}</td>`;
                            lvBody.appendChild(separatorRow);
                        }

                        // Create and append the LV row
                        const row = createLvRow(lv, false);
                        lvBody.appendChild(row);
                    }
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Fehler beim Laden des Leistungsverzeichnisses:', error);
            });
    }

function createLvRow(lv, isSaved = false) {
        const row = document.createElement('tr');
        row.dataset.lvId = lv.lv_id ? lv.lv_id : lv.id;
        row.dataset.subserviceInstanceId = lv.subservice_instance_id;

        row.innerHTML = `
            <td>${row.dataset.lvId}</td>
            <td class="text-column"><textarea class="form-control dynamic-height" ${isSaved ? 'data-saved="true"' : ''}>${lv.text}</textarea></td>
            <td class="turnus-column"></td>
            <td class="qm-column"></td>
            <td class="ae-column"></td>
            <td class="storno-column"></td>
            <td>
                ${isSaved ? `<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteLvRow('${row.dataset.lvId}', true)">Löschen</button>` : `<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteLvRow('${row.dataset.lvId}', false)">Löschen</button>`}
            </td>
        `;

        const textArea = row.querySelector('textarea');
        if (!isSaved) {
            textArea.addEventListener('input', function () {
                adjustHeight(this);
                markLvRowAsChanged(row);  // Zeile als geändert markieren
            });

            adjustHeight(textArea);
        }

        const turnusCell = row.querySelector('.turnus-column');
        if (lv.show_turnus) {
            const turnusDropdown = createTurnusDropdown(lv.turnus);
            turnusDropdown.value = lv.turnus || 'w1';
            turnusDropdown.addEventListener('change', function () {
                markLvRowAsChanged(row);  // Zeile als geändert markieren
            });
            turnusCell.appendChild(turnusDropdown);
        }

        const qmCell = row.querySelector('.qm-column');
        if (lv.show_qm) {
            const qmInput = document.createElement('input');
            qmInput.type = 'number';
            qmInput.className = 'form-control';
            qmInput.value = lv.qm || '';
            qmInput.addEventListener('change', function () {
                markLvRowAsChanged(row);  // Zeile als geändert markieren
            });
            qmCell.appendChild(qmInput);
        }

        const aeCell = row.querySelector('.ae-column');
        if (lv.show_ae) {
            const aeCheckbox = document.createElement('input');
            aeCheckbox.type = 'checkbox';
            aeCheckbox.checked = lv.ae || false;
            aeCheckbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
                markLvRowAsChanged(row);  // Zeile als geändert markieren
            });
            aeCell.appendChild(aeCheckbox);
        }

        const stornoCell = row.querySelector('.storno-column');
        if (lv.show_storno) {
            const stornoCheckbox = document.createElement('input');
            stornoCheckbox.type = 'checkbox';
            stornoCheckbox.checked = lv.storno || false;
            stornoCheckbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
                markLvRowAsChanged(row);  // Zeile als geändert markieren
            });
            stornoCell.appendChild(stornoCheckbox);
        }

        return row;
    }


How can I adjust my code to solve this problem?
EDIT:
Here again with picture step by step the procedure:
Step 1: add a new subservice
Step 2: in LV (List of service) we see the seperator with correct name and the services
Step 3: add a new subservice, but in same subservice
Step 4: here is the issue: the first one with "Fenster" is gone and rewrite with "Dach" one

Is "subservice type" referring to a specific technical detail here, or is it just your own domain terminology and all you're doing here just manipulating the DOM on a webpage?  Can you update this to a [mcve] as a runnable code snippet which demonstrates just the problem you're trying to describe?  And indicate what debugging you have done and where specifically in all this code is an unexpected result first observed?

Hi @David, by "subservice type," I’m referring to a concept in my domain, but essentially, I’m manipulating the DOM on a webpage. The goal is to allow users to add multiple instances of the same subservice type, with each instance having its own separator with a unique name and corresponding rows (LV entries) in the list. I have extended the post with pictures showing the procedure.

In that case... Can you update this to a [mcve] as a runnable code snippet which demonstrates just the problem you're trying to describe? And indicate what debugging you have done and where specifically in all this code is an unexpected result first observed?

@David I'm not sure how to do this. My code is already a lot and complex. I tried to minimize it and execute it myself but I can't. I am still a beginner sorry.
Is this perhaps what you want?
https://pastebin.com/qLT8B3Ut

Essentially you're at the step now where you need to do some debugging to narrow down the problem.  If you're not familiar with your browser's development/debugging tools, now is a great time to start.  Using your browser's script debugger, you can place breakpoints on key lines of code to pause execution of the code and step through it, line by line, observing the runtime behaviors and changing variable values.  This is how you can narrow down the problem to the first operation in your logic which produces an unexpected result.  That's where you'd want to start focusing.
